# Why am I getting this StackOverFlowException

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
    class Test
    {
        private int myFaveNumber; //fields
        private const int myLeastFaveNumber = 5;
        private string secretPassword = "Pickle";

        public int MyFaveNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return MyFaveNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    MyFaveNumber = value;
                else
                    myFaveNumber = 10;

            }
        }

        public int Math()
        {
            return myFaveNumber - myLeastFaveNumber;
        }

        public Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Secret password is " + secretPassword);

        }
        public Test(string two)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The full password is {0}", two);
        }






    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test quick = new Test();
            Console.WriteLine(quick.ToString());
            quick.MyFaveNumber = 5;
            Console.WriteLine(quick.Math());


            Test quicky = new Test("Drill");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

I am messing around as a beginner, and am wondering why I am getting a "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException". If you could help me figure this out that would be great. Also any tips are always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It should be  **`myFaveNumber`** not   **`MyFaveNumber`** = value;

```
set
{
   if (value > 0)
       myFaveNumber = value;
   else
       myFaveNumber = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part:

```
public int MyFaveNumber
{
    get
    {
        return MyFaveNumber;
    }

    ...
}
```

You've set the `MyFaveNumber` property to return itself. Likewise, in the setter:

```
set
{
    if (value > 0)
        MyFaveNumber = value;
    else
        myFaveNumber = 10;

}
```

You (conditionally) assign `MyFaveNumber`, causing the setter to call itself. Both of these scenarios will cause the property to recursively call its getter/setter over and over again until the program crashes.

You need to be getting/setting the private backing field `myFaveNumber` instead:

```
public int MyFaveNumber
{
    get
    {
        return myFaveNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value > 0)
            myFaveNumber = value;
        else
            myFaveNumber = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider property as a function.
When you write this functions

```
public int GetMyProperty()
{
    return GetMyProperty();
}

public void SetMyProperty(int value)
{
    if (value > 0)
        SetMyProperty(value);
}
```

You will obviously recognize that there is possibility in infinite recursive call which will "blow up" your stack(default size of the stack for .NET applications is 1 MB). So you increase size of the stack with every recursive call which happened in you program when you execute.

```
quick.MyFaveNumber = 5;
```

And you will get same exception in case when you will try to read value of the property

```
Console.WriteLine(quick.MyFaveNumber);
```

So correct way of using properties assign values to the underlying private field when needed validation is done.

```
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty
{

}
```